Uncaught runtime errors: ERROR process is not defined
My npm start has about 58 errors, almost all of them in webpack.config.js.  Now, when I stop Ctrl-C and restart (npm start), my browser shows the pictures below. I've stopped and restarted my back end server (node server.js). I've rebooted the system (Rocky Linux via Virtual Box). I'm at a loss.



